# Main Navigation Moves When a Link is Clicked

Tags: html, css, sass

I've tried to take screenshots to help describe the issue better but had no luck capturing one.

I'm trying to resolve the issue on my website, http://abrielshipley.com, where the main navigation appears to be positioned correctly.

When I click on one of the main navigation links, the main navigation then goes below the logo on the left-hand side. How can I fix the issue when one of the main navigation links is clicked does the main navigation still appear in the proper position on the top-right of the screen?

Here is some of the code for the main navigation elements in SASS:

```
nav
    width: initial
    border: none
    display: inline-block
    margin-right: 0
    position: absolute
    right: 4em
    &:active
        display: block
        position: static
        width: 100%
    li
        display: block
        line-height: 3.5em
        text-align: center
    li:first-of-type
        margin-right: 1.5em
    a
        border: none
        font-size: 1.125em
        display: list-item

header a
    color: #FFF
    cursor: pointer
    text-decoration: none
    text-transform: uppercase
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out
    &:hover
      color: #D8D8D8
    &:focus
      outline: 1px solid #F1F1F1
```

Comment: Because you are changing the position of the nav from absolute to static, why do you need position static on that ?, is there any other effect that you try to achieve when navigation is active ?

Comment: @JismonThomas The active code was there previously for another iteration of the site but wasn't removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove this :

```
&:active
    display: block
    position: static
    width: 100%
```